# I need to enable FIPS on a air gapped server

Tags: security

I have a 20.04 server that I need to enable FIPS on. The problem is that it is air gapped (aka no internet access). Is this possible?

Comment: The requirement for FIPS suggests that you have a budget to pay for the certification and support. Therefore, this seems a question for the Canonical (Ubuntu Advantage) sales staff, not community support volunteers. They have published sales literature on the topic that claims it's possible...but of course they don't really furnish detailed instructions until you have paid.